# How to use the DeBERTa model by He et al. (2022) on Spyder?

Tags: python, nlp, spyder

I have recently successfully analyzed text-based data using sentence transformers based on the BERT model. Inspired by the book by Kulkarni et al. (2022), my code looked like this:

```
# Import SentenceTransformer
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
# use paraphrase-MiniLM-L12-v2 pre trained model
sbert_model = SentenceTransformer('paraphrase-MiniLM-L12-v2')
# My text
x='The cat cought the mouse'
# get embeddings for each question
sentence_embeddings_BERT= sbert_model.encode(x)
```

I would like to do the same using the DeBERTa model but can't get it running. I managed to load the model, but how to apply it?

```
import transformers 

from transformers import DebertaTokenizer, AutoTokenizer, AutoModel
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("microsoft/deberta-v3-base")
model = AutoModel.from_pretrained("microsoft/deberta-v3-base")                    

sentence_embeddings_deBERTa= model(x)
```

The last line does not run, error message is:

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'size'

Any experienced DeBERTa users out there?

Thanks
Pat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to SO ;)
When you call `encode()` method it would `tokenize` the input then encode it to the tensors a transformer model expects, then pass it through model architecture. When you're using `transformers` you must do the steps manually.

```
from transformers import DebertaTokenizer, DebertaModel
import torch
# downloading the models
tokenizer = DebertaTokenizer.from_pretrained("microsoft/deberta-base")
model = DebertaModel.from_pretrained("microsoft/deberta-base")
# tokenizing the input text and converting it into pytorch tensors
inputs = tokenizer(["The cat cought the mouse", "This is the second sentence"], return_tensors="pt", padding=True)
# pass through the model 
outputs = model(**inputs)

print(outputs.last_hidden_state.shape)
```

Lastly, you must know what kind of output you're supposed to work with.

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked out well! Allow me two more questions: What is the best way to deal with multiple sentences (I guess not using "for")? And regarding the output, how do I get the embeddings?

Comment: If you have a couple of sentences it can be good to pass it as a whole, otherwise using the `for` block will definitely help you to monitor the progress and do whatever you wish in a more flexible manner. I have updated the answer based on the first option.

Comment: Great, the `padding=True` option solved it! To get the embeddings on the level of the sentences, is it correct to look at the first sequence via `outputs.last_hidden_state[:,0,:]`, or do I have to pool across sequences somehow?

Comment: I guess it would be so related to the application but fortunately, there are plenty of places to look at for gaining more knowledge like [here](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/7540)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, and for all of your help!